# How are the lowest level standard library functions written?

Tags: c++

I understand that most programming languages have standard libraries. I also understand that many libraries make use of functions and methods from other libraries and when creating a new library, a programmer can use existing code from other libraries.

My question is, how are the most basic library functions written? The functions that are used by many other libraries, functions, or code in general. For example, the originating function that writes a character to the screen. Are these foundation functions written in assembly?

I am a relatively new CS student so I apologize if I'm not using the proper language.

Comment: Things like console IO use OS specific API calls; how the OS implements those API functions will vary.

Comment: Isn't this question too board?

Comment: In nearly all modern OS's, the screen output is written in C or C++, but there will be some interaction with hardware, whether that is poking bytes into a textbased framebuffer, or storing the text in a serial port FIFO to be sent out on the "transmit" line, or the complexity of writing a variable width font onto a graphical display (which would be many hundreds if not thousands of lines of code). Exactly how that works depends on exactly how the hardware works...

Comment: @user3528438:  yes, the question is too `board` because it is making me sleepy.  It could also be too broad because each library function is implemented differently.

Answer (score 1):

a dynamic library (.dll in windows) is exactly like an executable file(.exe in windows) in fact the both are in the same file format ,PE format (portable executable)
the different is that the dynamic library doesn't "start" the execution by it's own ( you usually don't include an entry point in it's file)

so a dynamic library is exactly like an exe (both have code and data), and as for the OS core libraries like user32.dll and kernal32.dll ntdll.dll (in case of windows),they built as every executable been built (most of them with c/c++), and whatever your programming platform(.net/native c/assembly) your program must call functions in these libraries to "get connected to the world" let's see an example.
when you ask your c++ program to show a message on the screen, you usually do that by calling a function in the c++ standard library , which in turn calls the OS functions which in turn calls the hardware drivers which "KNOW HOW" to show the message on this particular screen of the machine.

so if you want to define the layers that your programming requests will go throw that will be:

1. call to a function in a library in the c++ standard library.
2. call to a user mode operating system library.
3. call to a kernel mode operating system library.
4. the OS calls the hardware driver that is related to the output(like the screen when you want to show "anything" on the screen.

don't think of the assembly as the language that can do anything , your c++ code is actually an assembly/binary code after it's compiled- unless it's a virtual machine like .net or java which needs an additional layer at the top

what makes the OS libraries important that they just "know" how to deal with the OS, because they know where are exactly the OS data structures.

Answer (score 1):

In the C and C++ languages, library functions are usually written in C or C++, then compiled.  It is also used to test out the compilers.

Some compiler vendors may write libraries in assembly language (after compiling in high level language), for performance or space reasons.

A classic example is the `memcpy` function.  It would be written in assembly to take advantage of a processor's block copy instructions.

Some languages write their library functions using other languages.  For example, Java may write it's JVM function in C, get them working, then optimize them using assembly language.

As far as accessing platform stuff, this depends on the compiler.  Some platforms don't have screens.  Some platforms require the shop to write customized drivers that the compiler's code executes (such as embedded systems).  Some library functions call functions in the Operating System.